# Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'

Tags: javascript, jquery, slice

I'm newbie to the  Javascript/Jquery world.
I have a div with several links and i want to collect the url's .

Then i want to extract from those href's the last 9 characters (actually  i wish to optimize it and collect the digits independently the length at the end of each string).I tried to extract them  with the `slice()` method but it does not work.

In console the error is

> Object doesn't support property or method 'slice'

Can i convert the object to a string ? Your help is appreciated !
The code is the following

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var $posts= $('a.entry_title').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('href');
  });

  var posts1 = $posts[0].slice(-9);
  var posts2 = $posts[1].slice(-9);

  var posts = ["MyURL"+ posts1,"MyURL"+posts2]
  $('#div1').load(posts[0] + " .shadow3");
  $('#div2').load(posts[1] + " .shadow3");

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You see Object doesn't support because [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) returns a jQuery object.

Use [.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) instead because it returns an array on which slice would work

```
var $posts= $('a.entry_title').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Result would be

```
["link1", "link2", "link3"....] // just a sample
```

If you wish to get an array of hrefs with last nine characters of each link you can use map this way

```
var $posts= $('a.entry_title').map(function(){
   return $(this).attr('href').slice(-9); // or you can do your own magic
});
```

Result would look like this

```
["k1", "k2", "k3"....] // after slicing the words
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next one:

```
var hrefs = []; // list of collected and sliced hrefs.
var $posts= $('a.entry_title').each(function() {
    // slice & push each href into list.
    hrefs.push($(this).attr('href').slice(-9));
});
console.log('href list:', hrefs); // control result.
var posts = ["MyURL"+ hrefs[0],"MyURL"+hrefs[1]]
```